Previous Schengen overstay, now applying for UK Business visa
I'm Moroccan and I had a valid student visa in 2007 in France and then I was asked to leave by France and they took my passport as I didn't complete my study after 2 years. I stayed in France for the next 4 years without a valid card.
I returned back to Morocco in 2012 by my own without a passport as I requested for a "Laisser Passer" from the Moroccan embassy in France.
In 2013 I started working for a company and now they want to send me to the UK for a visit of 10 days completely paid by my employer. I have a new passport obviously and I want to know if this will have any issues with the UK.
If I want to later ask for another Schengen visa for work will my old foolish stay be an issue knowing that this happened more than 12 years ago?


In 2014 I started working for a company and now they want to send me to the UK for a visit of 10 days completely paid by my employer. I have a new passport obviously and I want to know if this will have any issues with the UK.

This could certainly be an issue. I believe you will be asked about it during your application and a failure to disclose it can have very serious consequences, see e.g. applying for UK visa after attempting an overstay in the united states
Depending on your current situation (including your financial situation and travel history since your return to Morocco), you may be able to overcome it but your overstay was quite serious and the UK tends to be strict about this.

If I want to later ask for another Schengen visa for work will my old foolish stay be an issue knowing that this happened more than 12 years ago?

It's less likely to be an issue in this case. Applications for Schengen visas do not require you to disclose past infringements and bans or data retention periods are relatively short in the EU, if you even had a ban. A French IRTF only lasts for 5 years. After 12 years, chances are that it wouldn't come up at all.
Finally, if you somehow end up living in France again, the overstay and period of illegal stay can be held against you in naturalization proceedings. In other words, it might be nearly impossible to become a French citizen by naturalization, for your whole life.

I don't think I ever got an IRTF as I went back to my country by my own means and no one arrested me in France or at the port.
In addition I'm in the process of applying to the UK and I don't see anywhere where I should mention it as for most questions it's asking about last 10 years history travel.

In addition, all these things happened more than 12 years ago so not sure how much data is being held still.

@Rahim The UK wouldn't routinely receive any data from France in the first place, even back when it was in the EU, so if they don't ask, it might not come up there either. That said, given the seriousness of the consequences, I would be very careful not to try to hide it.

Thanks a lot this helps and gives me a little hope to have the visa accepted!

@Rahim The UK visa application asks about travel history for the last 10 years, but the question about immigration history (overstaying etc) is not time-bound. The UK requires applicants to disclose all such events, irrespective of how long ago or what country.

I haven't completed yet the application but so far I see nowhere where it asks for it. All immigration history is only for last 10 years (which kinda makes sense).

@Rahim UK visa application form asks: "For either the UK or any other country, have you ever been: Refused a visa, Refused entry at the border, Refused permission to stay or remain, Refused asylum, Deported, Removed, Required to leave, Excluded or banned from entry", you were likely required to leave and will have to disclose that. This does not have a 10 year timeout, sadly.
